# Архиватор на пхп

Tags: php

Два часа себе голову ломаю, никак не могу понять, по какой причине он не архивирует! Может кто подскажет, где тут ошибка?

```
<?
//папка в которой будет размещен архив
$archive_dir = "/fakegen/";
//папка с исходными файлами
$src_dir = "/fakegen/jimm/";

//создание zip архива
$zip = new ZipArchive();
//имя файла архива
$fileName = 132".zip";
if ($zip->open($fileName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
    fwrite(STDERR, "Error while creating archive file");
    exit(1);
}

//добавляем файлы в архив все файлы из папки src_dir
$dirHandle = opendir($src_dir);
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dirHandle))) {
    $zip->addFile($src_dir.$file, $file);
}
//закрываем архив
$zip->close();

fwrite(STDOUT, "Archive created\n");

exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: @bazaev05, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Знаете, вот нет никакого желания читать вашкодводнустрочку.
Отредактируйте ваш вопрос до читабельного состояния

Comment: Что скрипт пишет при запуске, как вызываете и т.п. Это уже не телепатия, тут гадалки нужны.

Как минимум:

    // $fileName = 132".zip";
    $fileName = "132.zip";

Comment: Вот я поражаюсь таким вопросам, не что бы error_log привести, где именно скрипт обламывается ? Зачем ? Тут же все телепаты, и так поймут что здесь не так!

Comment: А на каком этапе ошибка? Выводит это:"fwrite(STDERR, "Error while creating archive file");" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поработать с готовой библиотекой. Вот миникод для первых проб:

```
<?php
require_once("pclzip.lib.php"); // подключаем библиотеку
if (file_exists("archive.zip")) {unlink("archive.zip");} // удаляем старый файл архива
$arc = new PclZip("archive.zip"); // создаем новый архив
?>
```

А вот сама ООП библиотека: [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/pclzip-downloads).

Comment: У тебя вроде всё работает.Архив создается и распаковывается без ошибок Только не совсем понимаю, что это на твоем сайте и для чего ОНО?Дружеский совет: если контент маленький расположи его по центру, увеличь шрифт,добавь миниописание о чем он и убери ты этот агресивный дизайн черного цвета, сделай сайт дружелюбней.